# Invalid date on Highcharts / Highstock

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime, highcharts

I'm trying to rendering a Column Chart using Highchart/Highstock, but I'm receiving a Invalid Date message on the X axis.

This is my "series" code:

```
series: [
                {name: 'MCGC Av. Oitis Esquina de Azaléias - pH', 
                 data: [ [Date.UTC(2014,11,10,16,19),7.58]], 
                 tooltip: { valueDecimals: 2}},
                {name: 'MCGC Rua Buganvílias, 1401 - pH', 
                 data: [ [Date.UTC(2014,11,11,11,19),7.47]], 
                 tooltip: { valueDecimals: 2}},
                {name: 'MCGC Avenida Azaléias - Campo de Golfe - pH', 
                 data: [ [Date.UTC(2014,11,19,15,34),7.75]], 
                 tooltip: { valueDecimals: 2}},
                {name: 'MCGC Rua dos Narcisos, 135 - pH', 
                 data: [ [Date.UTC(2014,11,26,16,38),6.75]], 
                 tooltip: { valueDecimals: 2}}]
```

The full code: http://jsfiddle.net/71cbebx6/

Thanks!

Comment: Is this what you are expecting? http://jsfiddle.net/71cbebx6/1/  I have just removed the double brackets so instead of [[Date.UTC(...), 7.47]], I said [Date.UTC(...), 7.47]

Comment: Unfortunately not! Look I have 4 dates. All of them in December! Your version is showing 8 dates in January!
If you comment 3 of 4 items of "series", it's works fine... the message "invalid date" that was showing on bottom left side is not showing any more. Look: http://jsfiddle.net/71cbebx6/2/
But I need a version to work fine with 2 or more item on "series"! Get it?

Comment: What about this one? http://jsfiddle.net/71cbebx6/3/  If this is what you try to achieve, maybe you should look on the demo page, there must be some better configurations that suit you.

Comment: Set also a [pointRange](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.column.pointRange)

Comment: Well, I found a solution for this issue: When I remove the string "StockChart" from this code: `$('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {` , everything works fine! Thanks everyone!